# Using Commands in a Shortcut Target

Tags: windows, shortcuts

Is it possible to put commands into a shortcut target? I recently swapped hard drives and now I've got a bunch of shortcuts going to the wrong drive letter. I really want to get "cd.." working - is this possible?

Comment: *I really want to get "cd.." working[.]* I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you just need a shortcut to the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just change the drive letter of the shortcut using the properties selection.

Comment: i could do that but if i change drives again in the future, then i'll have the same problem. in question is the shortcuts that run different games for dosbox that i've made myself. there's over 100 of them, and i would want to copy them going onto new systems in the future. but i don't fancy doing this job more than once if i don't have to..

Comment: Another thing you can do is possibly change the drive assignments from the drive manager....all except c:

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the Old drive letter was `O:` and your New drive letter is `N:`.

You can do any of the following:

- change the drive letter from `O:` to `N:` in the shortcuts' properties
- change the drive letter of your partition from `N:` to `O:` to match the old shortcuts
- map the new drive's root as a network drive (`\\localhost\N$`) to the old drive letter `O:`
- make a virtual drive `O:` that maps to your new drive's root: `subst O: N:\`